# Как сделать перенос на новую строку с определенного символа Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть запрос, сейчас все в одну строку: `| text [ | text | text ] | text [ | text ] | text`

Как сделать перенос, чтобы каждая новая строчка начиналась с знака **|** и текстом после него до следующего знака

Comment: Можно строку разбить на массив методом `split()` и выводить каждый элемент массива в отдельной строке

Comment: а как выводить каждый элемент массива в отдельной строке?

Comment: Я vue не знаю, должно быть как то так: `<template v-for="item in items">{{ item }} <br /> </template>` где **items** ваш массив

Comment: @Alexander Поясните, почему так не стоит делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразуем строку в массив с разделителем **|**

```
const str = '| text [ | text | text ] | text [ | text ] | text';
const listRender = str.split('|')
```

Значение `listRender` сохраним в состоянии

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      list: listRender
    };
  },
};
```

Результат выводим при помощи `v-for`:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in list">
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-silence-3yksc6?file=/src/App.vue)